# Проблема с прокруткой "новостной" ленты

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть так называемая "новостная" лента. Там выводятся не новости а плитки. Плитки с текстом которые подгружаются из БД.
так вот. 
В вк при прокрутке новостей новости автоматически подгружаются сами. Я решил сделать что-то похожее.
Использую JS и функция scroolTop(). Я делаю так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var height = screen.height,
        append_height = height/2,   
        elements = 49, //сколько плиточек
        append = false;

    console.log("height " + height);
    console.log("append_height " + append_height);

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        $('a.text').text($(this).scrollTop());

        if($(this).scrollTop() > append_height) {
            $('a.text-1').text("scrollTop() > append_height: " + $(this).scrollTop() + " " + append_height);
            for(var i = 0;i <= elements; i++) {
                $('.feed-main ul').append('<li class="link-block">' + i + '</li>');
            }
            append_height+=height;
            $('a.text-2').text("append_height+=height = " + append_height);
            console.log("append_height " + append_height);
        }


    });
});
```

Для дебага я вывожу в консоль и в теги *a* информацию.

И так. Когда доходит до таких значений(дебаг):

7669
SCROLLTOP() > APPEND_HEIGHT: 6738 6656
APPEND_HEIGHT+=HEIGHT = 7680

Дальше плитки не подгружаются(для теста просто сделал добавление в конец ul). Почему - понять не могу. Что это может быть?

Comment: а код вывода из db как выглядит ?

Comment: @LenovoID он ещё не реализован. но суть будет такая. При прокрутке будет отсылаться ajax запрос на сервлет(я делаю сайт на JavaEE). Сервлет делает запрос к бд, вытягивает элементы и возвращает всё что вытянул ответом. По приходу ответа я JS-ом разбираю это всё и формирую плитки таким же способом - append().

Comment: блин - я думал js + php , тут я смогу , а о этом не знаю , прости

Comment: @LenovoID так мне нужно понять почему из моего примера просто не добавляются ниже. Почему не срабатывает append.
Сейчас я просто добавляю li-и для теста. не вытягиваю из бд пока что.

Comment: по сути , обычный вертикальный слайдер только вместо img у тебя должны быть новости , т.е некий block который выводится в цикле а внутри его уже те самый новости , лично я бы так сделал

Comment: Поставьте точку остановы напротив условия if, тогда возможно что-то будет понятно